# How do you sum fractions like this?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this fraction in Google Sheets:

```
1/8
2/8
3/8
4/8
5/8
6/8
7/8
8/8
```

How do I sum this digits?
For example if I have:

`1 4/8 + 3/8 = 1 7/8`

How do I make this formula?
I have formatted my cells like `#\ ?/8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can sum cells:

  ```
  =A8+A4+A3
  ```

[image]

- you can create **named ranges**:

```
=_88+_48+_38
```

[image]

- or use combination:

```
=1+_48+_38
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SUM function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669) if you are summing the fractions you listed in the box. However, if you've formatted your fractions like `1 4/8`, then the function won't return the correct sum. I would recommend reformatting your fractions from `1 4/8` to just `12/8` so that you can use the SUM function.